# What is wrong with my fstab?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster

I've been trying to run the directions in this page with my Raspberry Pi 4: https://members.apex-internet.com/sa/linux_web_filter.html. The line I get stuck at is this line:

```
tmpfs /var/log/e2guardian tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,uid=e2guardian,gid=e2guardian,mode=0755,size=100m 0 0
```

Every time I add that to the fstab, and reboot, I no longer can connect with my Raspberry Pi 4 via ssh. With other tools, like ping, I find that it is unreachable. When I revert back to the old version of fstab, it appears back on the network.

When I run `mount -fav`, it prints out that the tmpfs mount was successfully mounted. But when I try `mount -a`, I get the following error:

```
mount: /var/log/e2guardian: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on tmpfs, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Is that fstab line incorrect in the directions, or is it something else?

Comment: You should not reboot with that line in fstab until you can successfully manually mount it.  After you manually mount it and get that nearly meaningless error, check /var/log/syslog for the real error.

Comment: Is `/var/log/e2guardian` a directory?

Comment: `var/log/e2guardian` probably wasn't a directory when I attempted before. I just tried again, and it works. I think it is because I tried after the directory had been created by e2guardian (and I installed e2guardian).